# Change notification sound in iOS Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, push-notification, flutter-dependencies

I want to use my own sound in push notification in iOS platform of Flutter. Since I have no experience in iOS development, I am struggling with it.

In my app settings there are 3 notification sound options, so that user can choose notification sound. I have already implemented **local_notifications** package and although I am getting notifications in my app, I couldn't find how to use custom sound in push notification for iOS platform.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should replace this default given sound name to your sound name.

```
var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails(sound: 'slow_spring_board.aiff'); //put your own sound text here
```

(Before this, your sounds should be added to your project using Xcode)
Here is the link to how to add custom sound to your project for iOS devices using  Xcode: https://medium.com/@dmennis/the-3-ps-to-custom-alert-sounds-in-ios-push-notifications-9ea2a2956c11

**Note: Sound duration should be less than 30 seconds and the file name should not contain capital letters otherwise it will not work**

Comment: Where exactly is this line found sir?

Comment: @Lefty This is flutter code. I think this is property of local_notification package

Comment: What is the destination folder for aiff file?

Comment: @ZEHINZ shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtRTWdGrF3s

Comment: I placed it in the root folder and that worked. Thank you!

Comment: i have a 28 seconds duration notification. But its only appear about 5-10 seconds (the sound stopped after pop up notification disappear). Could you help my problem?